# How to switch to front camera in virtual device?

Tags: android

I am struggling with a really ridiculous thing. I am not able to find out how to switch from back camera to front camera in Android Virtual Device.

Here is the image:

[image: Image from camera]

Someone please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it's the third icon on top of the camera, try clicking around next time - it's an emulator! if it crashes just remake it

Comment: @kkarakk: I try but crash the whole emulator again and again, so I don't know that is the button to switch from back to front cam, the icon doesn't make any sense.

Comment: try  making a new emulator? if same issue, update to newer/older OS emulator and see if issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the front camera you need to click on the last button.Which is shown your image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But when I click on it, it crash my virtual device and every time I open camera, it crash again and again. Can you please guide me more.

Comment: @LuongTruong which virtual device you are using?.

Comment: I am using the virtual device from Android Studio, not the real one. API 27